# find out the previous URL and the value after hash # in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url, laravel-5.1

i'm developing a Laravel app. i'm looking for a way to figure out which page the user is coming from to save that value in the session and redirect to it later. so far i've found that you can use methods such as `URL::previous()` and `Redirect::back()->getTargetUrl()` to get the previous URL. however, the problem is that these methods do not grab the value after the URL hash. so, if a user is coming from a URL like this:

`http://example.com/#/application/some/route`

the ouput of the aforementioned methods is:

`http://example.com`

how can i grab the full URL, including the value after hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can i grab the full URL, including the value after hash?

That is not possible server-side – because the hash part of the URL is of client-side importance only, and is not even send to the server.

So if you want that info, you must get it via JavaScript, while the user is on that page.

Comment: i see. is it possible to write data to the session / cache with javascript to make it available on the server side? specifically i was trying to use Laravel's `Session::put('key','value')` to store a value and retrieve it with `Session::pull('key')`. i suppose there's no way of storing a value like that from the client-side?

Comment: You would make a request to the server (AJAX), so that the server can store it into the session.

Answer (score 0):

The `hash` portion of a URL is used on the client side only. It will never appear in server logs, requests, or as part of a `REFERRER` string. And will not sent to the server.

You have to use javascript.